# System.InvalidOperationException: 'session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 98 using Selenium and C#

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm making a game application just for me. This app was working last night but when i wake up today i saw it the program did not work today. It says,

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 98
Current browser version is 100.0.4896.60 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

I tried a lot of way but ı couldn't fix it.

1. I gave the file path like

   ```
        string lobby = "https://translate.google.com";
        var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
        service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
        var ayar = new ChromeOptions();
        ayar.AddArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
        ayar.AddArguments("--start-maximized");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\ss\source\repos\hmmm\hmmm\driver\");
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(lobby + "/");
   ```
2. I deleted nuGet and reinstalled with version 98 but still ı have same error how can ı fix it? Also my normal chrome browser version is 100. Thanks for your answers

Comment: "I deleted nuGet and reinstalled with version 98". Why? If you have Chrome 100 installed take a chromedriver with the same version. If you use chromedriver version 98 then you need chrome 98 installed.

Comment: @Ralf really really thank you it worked and ı have a question ı dont want to open a new quest thats why ım asking here. do you know, is there any selenum project to see oop on github or something ı mean ı want to see how can ı make good selenium project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 98 Current browser version is 100.0.4896.60 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

...implies that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chrome=100.0*
- But you are using *chromedriver=98.0*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=98.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/98.0.4758.102/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports Chrome version 98

So there is a clear mismatch between *chromedriver=98.0* and the *chrome=100.0*

---

### Solution

As you are using ***chrome=100.0*** ensure that *ChromeDriver* is updated to  [ChromeDriver v100.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=100.0.4896.60/) level.